# Using Dojo's modularity to separate javascript files

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I'm fairly new to Dojo, and I've been trying to develop a map application using Esri's Javascript API, which is based on Dojo framework.

I decided to go ahead and start from the ground up by separating the different parts of the application into different JS files, and load them using Dojo's AMD loader.

Here is what I have so far, and the while page is currently working and Firebug verifies that the javascript files are being accessed correctly, none of the javascript in the dojo application are working.

If you have worked with this before, and could point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it.

Main HTML Page:

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    </head>
    <body class="nihilo">
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
                <p class="chromeframe">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">activate Google Chrome Frame</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->
        <div id="header">
            <div id="logo">
                <a href="http://www.co.washington.mn.us/"><img src="img/clearlogo.png" alt="Washington County Logo" /></a>
            </div>              
            <div class="login">
                <a id="loginLink" href=""></a>
            </div>
            <div id="title">
                <h1></h1>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div id="clear" style="clear:both;"></div>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="sidebar">
                <div class="inner">
                    <div id="edit" >
                        <h2 id="addText" >Add Features:</h2>
                        <div id="editor">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <h2>Find Address:</h2>
                    <div id="searchAddr"></div>
                    <h2>Find Name:</h2>
                    <div id="searchName"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="map">  
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>

        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>

        <!--<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>-->
        <script>
            var dojoConfig = {
                parseOnLoad: false,
                packages: [
                    {name: "app", location: "/new_app/js/app"}
                ],
                has: {
                    "dojo-firebug": true,
                    "dojo-debug-messages": true
                },
            };
        </script>
        <script src="//serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.5/" data-dojo-config="parseOnLoad: true, isDebug: true"></script>
        <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="js/sha512.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Main JS:

```
require([
    "app/ui",
    "app/app"
], function(UI, App) {

    var ui = new UI();
    var app = new App();
    app.start();

});
```

UI JS:

```
define([
    "dojo/dom",
    "dijit/Dialog",
    "dijit/form/Form",
    "dojo/_base/connect",
    "dijit/form/Button",
    "dojo/request",
    "dojo/dom-attr",
    "dojo/json",
    "dojo/domReady!"], function(declare, Dialog) {
// Class with custom properties and methods
    return declare(null, {
        loginText: '<div id="loginForm"><label for="email">User:</label> <input id="email" type="text" name="email" /><br /><label for="password">Password:</label> <input id="password" type="password" name="password" id="password"/><br /><button id="submitLogin">Login</button></div>',
        messageDialog: new Dialog({
            title: "Message",
            style: "width:400px;"
        }),
        loginDialog: new Dialog({
            title: "User Login",
            content: loginText,
            style: "width: 400px;"
        }),
        loginButton: new Button({
            label: "Login",
            onClick: login()
        }, "submitLogin"),
        start: function() {
            checkLogin();
        },
        login: function() {
            ui.loginDialog.hide();
            var username = dojo.byId("email");
            var password = dojo.byId("password");
            dojo.attr(password, "value", hex_sha512(dojo.attr(password, "value")).toUpperCase());
            request.post("index.php", {
                data: {
                    a: "login",
                    p: dojo.attr(password, "value"),
                    email: dojo.attr(username, "value"),
                },
                handleAs: "json",
                timeout: 10000
            }).then(function(response) {
                checkLogin();
            });
        },
        checkLogin: function() {
            request.post("index.php", {
                data: {
                    a: "login_check"
                },
                handleAs: "json",
                timeout: 10000
            }).then(function(result) {
                link = dom.byId("loginLink");
                if (result.login == "success") {
                    link.innerHTML = "Logout";
                    dojo.attr(link, "href", "?a=logout");
                    if (ui.loginDialogHandle)
                        dojo.disconnect(ui.loginDialogHandle);
                }
                else {
                    link.innerHTML = "Login";
                    dojo.attr(link, "href", "#");
                    ui.loginDialogHandle = dojo.connect(link, "onclick", ui.loginDialog, "show");
                }
            });
        }
    })
});
```

App JS:

```
define([
    "esri/map"
], function(Map) {
    return declare(null, {
        map: null,
        start: function() {
            map = new esri.Map("map", {
                center: [-92.881154, 45.166838],
                zoom: 14,
                basemap: "gray"
            })
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: I think that you really should put those `<script>` tags up in the `<head>`, the ones with `src` attribute first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see [Classy JavaScript with dojo/_base/declare](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/declare/). It describes how to define classes in Dojo.

You have wrong sequence or arguments in `define([...], function(<here>))`

UI JS:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/dom",
    "dijit/Dialog",
    "dijit/form/Form",
    "dojo/_base/connect",
    "dijit/form/Button",
    "dojo/request",
    "dojo/dom-attr",
    "dojo/json",
    "dojo/domReady!"], function(declare, dom, Dialog, connect, Button, request) {
```

App JS:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "esri/map"
], function(declare, Map) {
```

Also in App JS you've defined `Map` so no need of writing

```
map = new esri.Map("map", {
```

but

```
map = new Map("map", {
```

PS: there might be dragons... these are just a few things I've noticed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comments. I made your suggested changes, and I'm still facing some issues. Firebug isn't showing any errors, and the functions inside the classes are not running. From your perspective, am I approaching this problem in an appropriate manner? I have not worked much with javascript classes and any suggestions you have as to starting a project like this would be very helpful as well.

Comment: Could you describe your project's catalogue structure? Or better sketch it on jsfiddle.net? Also to check AMD working you could put `console.log('bla-bla-bla')` right before `return declare(...`.

Comment: I have started to see some progress, I did a lot of researching on javascript's this operator and have managed to get most of the functionality working, with this object oriented model.